# How to change icon and text to a ApplicationBarIconButton?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to make my click event change an ApplicationBarIconButton. My ApplicationBarIconButton looks like this:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="driveAction" Click="drive_click" IconUri="/img/car.png" Text="kör" />
```

I want the *IconUri* to change from */img/car.png* to ex. */img/car-stop.png* and the text value from *kör* to *passagera*. I tried the function below, but it only causes my app to shut down.

```
private void drive_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.driveAction.Text = "passagera";
  this.driveAction.Source = "/img/car-stop.png";
}
```

What is wrong? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

The default ApplicationBar requires you to access the buttons through the ApplicationBar object. To accomplish this you must know the index of the button that you want to change

```
private const int DriveButtonIndex = 0;

private void drive_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[DriveButtonIndex];
    button.IconUri = new Uri("/img/car-stop.png", UriKind.Relative);
    button.Text = "passagera";
}
```

There are a few custom ApplicationBars that allow you to name your buttons. But I've found that the above solution always works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Get it directly from the application bar list -

```
ApplicationBar.Buttons[0].Text = "passagera";
ApplicationBar.Buttons[0].Source = "/img/car-stop.png";
```

You could also query the list of buttons for a specific icon as a more tenable long-term solution, but if you only have one button and that's not going to change, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ApplicationBarIconButton` is actually a native control and not a true XAML object you cannot refer to it by name.

You can refer to it by index if create in XAML. Alternatively you could create it in code and then you can maintain a named reference you can use.